# How to get Material-UI Button attribute in onClick?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to get the attribute of Material-UI Button?. I've tried the `getAttribute()` but it gives me `null`. I know this is possible using normal `<button>` tags but I want to try using Material-UI button.

My button-

```
<Button 
    variant="outlined" 
    id={button1} 
    button-key="buttonAttribute"
    onClick={this.isClicked}>
    MyButton
</Button>
```

click function -

```
isClicked = (e) => {
   const attButton = e.target.getAttribute('button-key')
   console.log(attButton)
}
```

My console returns `null`.
How can it return `buttonAttribute`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `currentTarget` instead

```js
e.currentTarget.getAttribute("button-key")
```

You can also use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) by prefixing your attribute name with `data-*`. It's a good practice to use this instead because it creates a '*namespace*' for your custom attribute so they won't clash with the standard HTML attributes.

```js
<Button
  onClick={(e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.buttonKey);
  }}
  data-button-key="buttonAttribute"
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64305609/how-to-get-material-ui-button-attribute-in-onclick]

Answer (score 0):

It is showing `null` because if you log the `e.target` then you will see the `span` element which is present inside button component and you are passing id to its root element which is a `div`.